# MPAndroidChart hide bubble size value

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I'm drawing a bubble chart using MPAndroidChart, and want to hide the bubble size value. How do I do that?

[image: My current graph]
How do I hide the "5' and "66.8"?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using bubbleDataSet.setDrawValues(false);

**Code:**

```
        BubbleDataSet set1 = new BubbleDataSet(yVals1, "DS 1");
        set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[0], 130);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
```